# The easiest way to access device on another private network via shared device

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

So I have this setup:

- Device 1 on my home LAN. This is "dumb" device and I cannot configure anything but IP address and default gateway there.
- Device 2 on my home LAN which is also part of my another network (ZeroTier). It's running Linux.
- Device 3 which is not part of my home LAN. It is also running Linux and hosting some services which I'd like to access from Device 1.
- Router at home. This is also some cheap one and I can't seem to be able to add routes there.

What would be the easiest way to connect to `Device 3` from `Device 1`? I tried doing this https://serverfault.com/a/586553 but couldn't make it work and don't even know if this is supposed to work since `Device 1` and `Device 3` are in different networks. I was also thinking that maybe I could connect `Device 1` and `Device 2` directly to each other and use `Device 2` as a "default gateway" but that would require some extra equipment so software only solution would be preferred if possible. Bear in mind I'm quite new to all the networking stuff so giving link to another source of information is appreciated as well.

Picture of the situation:

[image: Picture of the situation]

Comment: Verify with Wireshark or `tcpdump` that 1) device 2 is actually forwarding the packets from 3 to 1 – receiving them via zerotier _and_ sending them out via ethernet – and 2) that both NAT rules are having effect; the packets being sent out from 2 to 1 should have their "source IP" translated to make it look like 2 is the original sender. ("On different networks" is, well, just normal network operation – but being unable to configure the target device is actually the reason the 'SNAT' rule is there.)

Comment: It seems on the `device 2` using `tcpdump` I can see:
1. Traffic comes in from `device 1 (192.168.0.11)` to `device 2 (192.168.0.17)` 

`18:30:20.792180 IP 192.168.0.11.55779 > 192.168.0.17.32400: Flags [S], seq 2993120990, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0`

2. NAT rules seem to work: `device 2 (10.147.18.147)` sends packet to `10.147.18.176 (device 3)`

`18:27:26.705463 IP 10.147.18.147.55549 > 10.147.18.176.32400: Flags [S], seq 3530373001, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0`


Then I don't see anything more

Comment: So after that I don't see anything more, including that the data isn't visible on `device 3` with `tcpdump`. Actually I realized that's another moving piece: now traffic is "sent" from ZeroTier interface but actually that's like VPN and the traffic has to be sent through the same (physical) interface which is part of the internal LAN (which is the adapter connecting the `device 2` to internet..) Is that a problem or is IPTables configuration just somehow blocking it?

Comment: The network stack doesn't really know nor care about the physical interface being the same. As far as it knows, the original ZeroTier encapsulated packet that arrived at device2 has *absolutely no relationship* with the new packet that's exiting device2 – it sees a UDP packet received by the zerotier daemon, it sees a TCP packet arriving at the virtual zt0 (then leaving eth0), but only the zerotier daemon knows that there's a relationship between the UDP packet and zt0.

Comment: So in other words, if you see in Device2's `tcpdump -ni eth0` that the TCP SYN packet was sent out towards Device1 (and with the expected NAT as well) – or, as I understand, if you ran tcpdump on Device1 and saw the packet arriving – then that tells you forwarding is working, the problem is that Device1 is not replying for some reason. Do you happen to know whether Device1 has the correct netmask configured? Does the "home router" have tcpdump? (I don't expect it would, but on the chance it runs OpenWRT, that'd be available.)

Comment: Wow, what an imbecile I am. I followed `tcpdump` all the way to `device 3` and noticed that the packet got finally lost between transfer from eth0 to zt interface.. because of flow rules in ZeroTier which blocks access to service from `device 2`. :) This was a good exercise overall though in debugging networking and your instructions and explanations in previous post @u1686_grawity were extremely helpful. Thank you!